# Cheapest way to get from Germany to India and back with flexible dates

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources, planning, flight-search-engines

I want to travel to Vandenmedu, India from Bochum, Germany.
Starting date would be around 20DEC15, return should be about 2 weeks later, i.e. 04JAN16

What bothers me:
I am flexible in both start- and return-dates, as well as the airports in both Germany and India, as long as I save money
but I'm having a hard time finding a search-engine that takes that flexibility into account.

I am looking for a search-engine that allows me to use a range of dates for both trips, with bonus points if I can just use regions instead of airports.

Answer (score 5):

For the flexible date and region search option you should try [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/) which provides flexibility of date via Month and shows map of region for destinations as shown below.

[image]

Also, you can try [ITASoftware](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) (this provide you a calender view where you can see the cheapest fare, but you will not be able to book using this site, so after your results go to another site and book from their with provided details).

[image]

Other than these some sites like [Orbitz](http://www.orbitz.com/flights/) provides flexible date and airport search within some distance as entered by you and [MakeMyTrip](http://www.makemytrip.com/) provides some instant suggestion on flexible dates once you have made search.

*These are MakeMyTrip images*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

www.adioso.com has fairly flexible searches where you can float dates and set regions as destination. Example DUS <-> DEL is US$ 896 depart 12/23, return Jan 4. This is probably as good as it's going to get: It's Christmas time with many people being off work, so flight prices are very high during that time